# Wpf Replace Text into RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

I work in WPF C#, i want to replace text into RichtextBox
i load my rtf File who contain picture it's work fine.

If i use this :

```
    ReposLettresFusion m_ReposLettresFusion = new ReposLettresFusion();
    TextRange range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd); 
    FileStream fStream = new FileStream(@pPath, FileMode.Create);

    range.Text = m_ReposLettresFusion.Fusion(pPkGuidLettre, range.Text);
    range.Save(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    fStream.Close();

    rtb.LoadRtf(pPath);
    m_ReposLettresFusion = null;
    range = null;
```

It's change my text but i loose my picture and fonts all my formatting.

How i can replace text and keep all formatting of the Rtf

Thank you

Comment: Your `TextRange` actualy takes the whole RichTextBox's content but when you use `.Text` I'd expect the TextRange to ignore everything else than real text. I'd probably use an other approach to replace the text. Can you provide more details on how the text has to be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void Fusion(ref Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox pRichTextControl)
        {

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in LettreFusion)
            {
                string keyword = entry.Key;
                string newString = entry.Value;

                TextRange text = new TextRange(pRichTextControl.Document.ContentStart, pRichTextControl.Document.ContentEnd);
                TextPointer current = text.Start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                while (current != null)
                {
                    string textInRun = current.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textInRun))
                    {
                        int index = textInRun.IndexOf(keyword);
                        if (index != -1)
                        {
                            TextPointer selectionStart = current.GetPositionAtOffset(index, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                            TextPointer selectionEnd = selectionStart.GetPositionAtOffset(keyword.Length, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                            TextRange selection = new TextRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                            selection.Text = newString;
                            pRichTextControl.Selection.Select(selection.Start, selection.End);
                            pRichTextControl.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                    current = current.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                }
            }
        }
```